# wordpress shortcode caching

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, shortcode

I've developed an plugin where i make use of shortcodes. One of these shortcodes retrieves external information through communicate with an API.

The function that's called by the shortcode, communicates several times with the API. How could i cache all separate calls.

Let me try to explain it with some code

**Example code**

```
public function generateData($atts, $content = null, $tag = null){
        // $this->API is a extended class to retrieve the API data
        // example one calling the api
        $data1 = $this->API->getData(array(
            'teamlevel' => 'beginner'
        ));

        $data2 = $this->API->getData(array(
            'competition' => 'baseball'
        ));
    }

    add_shortcode('getdata', 'generateData');

    class API {
        public function getData($params){
            // communicate with the api en return the data
        }   
    }
```

Above code is working but without caching. Now i've tried to make use of wordpress get_transient and set_transient on the following way

```
public function generateData($atts, $content = null, $tag = null){
        // $this->API is a extended class to retrieve the API data
        // example one calling the api

        // new chaining method cache
        // every data call could be cached, i thought this could be based on shortcode name ($tag)
        // set the shortcode name
        $this->API->cacheShortcodeName = $tag; // getdata

        $data1 = $this->API->cache()->getData(array(
            'teamlevel' => 'beginner'
        ));

        $data2 = $this->API->cache()->getData(array(
            'competition' => 'baseball'
        ));
    }

    add_shortcode('getdata', 'generateData');

    class API {
        private $cacheDuration;
        protected $cacheShortcodeName;

        public function getData($params){
            // before communication with the api check if there is cache with hasCache
            // 1. $this->hasCache
            // if result is true return cached data
            // 2. return cached data
            // else communicatie with the API en set new cache data
            // 3. retrieve data from api en set new cached data
        }

        // default cache duration (1 day) in seconds
        public function cache($cacheDuration = 86400){
            $this->cacheDuration = $cacheDuration;
            return $this;
        }

        public function hasCache(){
            // check if there is cache
            $cache = get_transient(md5($this->cacheShortcodeName));

            if(!empty($cache)){
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public function setCache($data){
            set_transient(md5($this->cacheShortcodeName), $data, $this->cacheDuration);
        }

        public function getCache(){
            $cache = get_transient(md5($this->cacheShortcodeName));
            return $cache;
        }
    }
```

But the problem is when the cache is saved within the function setCache each time the shortcode name is set, and therefore i think its overriding itself. How could i store every call separately?

Comment: How about making your cacheShortcodeName reflect the attributes in `$atts`, e.g. `md5(serialize($atts))`?

Comment: That could be a solution. But isn’t theire a way to get a unique identifyer. I was thinking to use the variable names: data1 and data2. But want to create it as dynamic as possible. (No hardcoded params passing for names)Something as get variable name when function is called

Comment: Unless you have two different shortcodes with the same attributes, $atts will be unique. You could always set `$atts["shortcode"] = $tag` to cover that case, if you do have two shortcodes with very similar functionality.